# jquery delay function wont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to make a delay between the animation and the toggling between hidden and visible of the transbox, the code works perfectly without a delay function (but everything loads at once), am i doing the delay function wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/qWszS/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code. I've made some changes to it, that should do the same thing:

```
$(".go1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".go2, .go3, .go4, .go5, .go6").hide("slow");
    $(".go1").animate({top: "0", left: '60%'}, "slow").delay(2000).queue(function() {
       $(".hide, .transbox").css("visibilty", "visible");
    });
});
```

- You didn't set any time for setTimout, so I removed it. You can add it back in if you want to execute the animation and show the elements at a later time.
- I've selected .go2 - .go6 with a single selector.

**Edit:** Made some corrections to the example.

Comment: This won't do what you want it to: `$(".hide").delay(2000).show();` as `.show()` will execute immediately, not after the delay.

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky It is untested code. How do you mean it didn't execute?

Comment: i replaced my code with yours in my html and the function just didnt run

Comment: no error, just nothing happens, im gonna post my entire code maybe that will help

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky There is no text within your anchor-tags, so there is nothing to click on. Either you can add text to them, if that is intended, otherwise you will have to catch the click-event of something else, like the wrapping div-element.

Comment: i have pictures in the divs- this is how it looks  [link](http://minus.com/mOkCEEDGq#2)
im working on this concept for my internship but im only a sophmore in college so im learning as i go. after an element is clicked, the others disappear, the clicked element moves to the center of the page and then the box and button are supposed to appear.

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky I found another error in my code example that is fixed now, so you could give it another try. However, are you sure that you are catching the click-event properly? It seems weird as nothing is happening. Do you get an alert if you change your code to `$(".go1").click(function(event){ alert("Click!") });` and click the anchor?

Comment: the updated code works to do the animation, but the box doesnt appear

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky Okay, so I noticed that you use `visibility: hidden` and not `display: none`, therefore `.show()` did not work. Updated my example again. I provided a fiddle as well, where you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/coffe_e/rvmJF/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6235/discussion-between-matthew-vitebsky-and-christofer-eliasson)

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` only affects operations that use the animation queue for that particular object.  It does not affect methods on that object that do not use the animation queue and it does not affect other lines of code following this that operate on other objects.

In a funny quirk of jQuery, `.hide()` or `.show()` does not use the animation queue so it doesn't work with `.delay()`, but `.hide(1)` or `.hide("slow")` does use the animation queue so it will work with `.delay()`.

So, to delay operations on other objects a fixed amount of time, you probably want to use setTimeout to schedule the operations for a future time.  To sequence operations so one starts when this one finishes, use the completion function for the first operation.

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but this rewritten code will fix a number of issues:

1. Combined all the hide operations into one selector.
2. Added a time to the setTimeout so they're is a delay after the hide before animation starts (since it appears you wanted a timeout there)
3. Instead of .delay(), I use the completion function of the animate to trigger the next action.

Here's the code:

```
$(".go1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from changing the location
    $(".go2, .go3, .go4, .go5, .go6").hide("slow");
    setTimeout(function() {
        var done = false;
        $(".go1").animate({top: "0", left: '60%'}, "slow");}, 1500, function() {
            // completion function is call once for each object animating
            // make sure we only execute our code once
            if (!done) {
                $(".hide").css("visibility", "visible", 1000)
                $(".transbox").css("visibility","visible");
                done = true;
            {
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Based on your comments, here's a significantly simpler form of code that shows the box and hide button after the animation is finished.  This one piece of code (combined with some changes to your HTML) replaces all the code you had in the fiddle:

```
$(".go").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".go").not(this).hide("slow");
    $(this).animate({top: "0", left: '60%'}, "slow", function() {
        $(".transbox, .hide").css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aKDgH/

If you want a further delay before the box shows, you can change the code to this and adjust the setTimeout time value to your liking:

```
$(".go").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".go").not(this).hide("slow");
    $(this).animate({top: "0", left: '60%'}, "slow", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {$(".transbox, .hide").css("visibility","visible");}, 1000);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aKDgH/9/

Comment: thanks for the help, but it didnt seem to work, i just did a direct swap of your code for mine and nothing happened. is there anything i have to fix in my html to make this work

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky - it's hard for me to see what you're page is trying to do.   Can you put your code into a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see exactly what you have and experiment with our own versions?  I tried making a jsFiddle of your code here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qWszS/, but there's no visible content (most of the links are just empty) so I have no idea what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky - you also need to describe (in words) exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qWszS/2/
i want the box and hide button to load after the animation is finished

Comment: I added a new version of code to my answer based on your comments and here's the jsFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aKDgH/.  Note: I drastically simplified your code (one piece of code works for all the items).

Comment: It still needs a delay after the animation, the box pops up as the word is still going up

Comment: As always, if you're making a claim like this, please show us a working example of your exact code so we can debug it and see what you see.  My jsFiddle doesn't have that issue so it's likely something you changed, but we have no way of knowing what you changed.  If you look at this version of my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aKDgH/6/ with the time lengthened so you can see exactly when things happen, you can see that the thing you clicked on moves to its position before the box becomes visible.

Comment: i didnt change the code, i just put it together in an html and then ran it in chrome and it pops up before the animation is finished, i think it would be perfect if there was like an extra second between the animation and the box pop up.
thank you for all your help

Comment: You did change something (HTML or javascript) from what I posted because the jsFiddle does not have that issue.  I need to see your code (both HTML and JS) to know what you changed.  Sorry, but I can't guess what is different in your actual page vs. the jsFiddle I posted.  I need to see your actual JS and HTML.

Comment: I think you're just seeing things.  The box doesn't become visible until the other item stops moving.  In any case, if you want to add a delay to when the box becomes visible, I've added that option to the end of my answer.

Comment: Also, in the code you posted on scribd, your last `<script>` tag is after `</body>` instead of before it.

Answer (score 0):

delay delays execution of next actions in the queue, and you've set it as last action. Set in before .animate and it will delay the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a timeout with no time!

```
setTimeout(function() {

   $(".go1").animate({top: "0", left: '60%'}, "slow");},1500);
   $(".hide").css("visibility", "visible", 1000);
   $(".transbox").css("visibility","visible");


}, 2000); //time!
```

Comment: the timeout was actually works without setting it haha but my problem is that the hide and transbox elements become visible before the animation finishes